# @USE & @Forward | SASS

Tags: css3, scss, preprocesador

les presento un caso donde quiero utilizar el @use y @forward y por mas que veo videos e intento no logro resolverlos.

Cuando intento crear la conexion en los archivos para realizar los cambios con sass me da error, ahora les mostrare mi directorio.

[image: Directorio del proyecto:]

Los siguientes pasos que realizo son los siguientes:

1. Creo dos carpetas diferentes con los nombres bases y componentes.
2. En la carpeta componentes agrego dos archivos: `_index.scss, _componentes.scss`
3. En la carpeta bases agrego dos archivos: `_index.scss, _variables.scss`
4. Por fuera de esas carpetas creo el archivo llamado app.scss que va hacer el compilador de los demas.
5. Al compilador **app.scss** le agrego lo siguiente:
   `@use 'bases' y @use 'componentes' con sus respectivos punto y coma` .
6. luego de que ya he programado el app.scss me dirigo hacia la carpeta bases/ e ingreso al archivo llamado index, dentro de el agrego el forward que va dirigido hacia variables codigo:
   `@forward` "variables"`;
7. Lo mismo al archivo index que esta en componentes:  `@forward` "componentes";
8. luego dentro de los archivos hago lo siguiente:

   Archivo (A): **_componentes.scss**:
   @use "../bases/variables" as v;
   p{
   color: v.$colorParrafo;
   };

   Archivo (B):  **_variables.scss**:
   $colorParrafo: #0f0;

"ACLARACION EN EL HTML HAY UN PARRAFO CON UN LOREM"

Ya realize los cambios de lugar, los archivos index estan dentro de cada carpeta y asi app.scss les da el seguimiento mendiante el @USE.

Ahora nada de eso surge efecto: quiero seguir usando sass pero no logro ver nada que me ayude a entrar a fondo en ese preprocessador.